# What is the most efficient and least laggy method for creating geofence?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to create a geofence that the user can click a button and it will alert whether or not the user is within the zone. I have a way to make this work but since I am new to iOS programming and swift, I am not sure if this is the most efficient way. Also, the user location dot sometimes lag on my app (it says the user is somewhere else instead of displaying the correct position). Is my implementation of the geofence correct? Or am I missing something?

The code that I am using is:

*To display user location:*

```
func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus() {
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        Map.showsUserLocation = true
    } else {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

*To set up the location manager*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }     
}
```

*And for creating the geofence*

```
@IBAction func checkLocation(sender: UIButton) {
    let geoFence = CLCircularRegion(center: defaultLocation, radius: 15, identifier: "fence")
    if geoFence.containsCoordinate(userLocation.coordinate) {
        let title = "You are in the zone"
        let okText = "OK"

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okayButton)

        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("no")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your location will frequently lag because Apple just gets confused.  What I don't get though is why you're using an "When in use" check and query in the status check, but then in view did load you're asking for "always".

Comment: @Gargoyle I'm just pulling together code snippets to try and create the map. I just realized this now. Should I delete "When in use" and keep "always" then? And also, do you think Google Maps would be less confused and laggy than Apple? Or are maps just confused in general. Thanks!

Comment: You should only use always if that what you need. As to maps...no it's just Apple getting confused where you are. Has nothing to do with the map app itself.